# Relation between polarization vector sums and propagators and the use of ghosts

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, propagator, gauge

It is commonly argued that, according to the BRST treatment, ghosts cannot appear as initial or final states, and that the only states that can be used as initial or final states are physical gauge bosons, that is those that are transversally polarized. These satisfy the following relation
\begin{equation}
S_{\mu\nu}=\sum_\lambda {\epsilon^{(\lambda)}_\mu}^\star \epsilon^{(\lambda)}_\nu=-g_{\mu\nu}+\frac{q_\mu n_\nu+q_\nu n_\mu}{q\cdot n}-\frac{q_\mu q_\nu}{(q\cdot n)^2}.
\end{equation}
On the other hand, covariant quantization of YM theories requires internal ghosts in order for amplitudes to be independent of the choice of the gauge parameter $\xi$. The propagator derived from a lagrangian with a Lorentz gauge fixing term looks like
\begin{equation}
\Delta_{\mu\nu}=\frac{-i}{p^2}\Bigg(g_{\mu\nu}-(1-\xi)\frac{p_\mu p_\nu}{p^2}\Bigg)=\frac{-i}{p^2}L_{\mu\nu}.
\end{equation}
It is obvious that the tensors $S_{\mu\nu}$ and $L_{\mu\nu}$ are not the same. In QED one usually argues that the Ward identity holds, and thus it is possible to substitute $S_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow {S'}_{\mu\nu}=-g_{\mu\nu}$ (although formally they are not the same) and use the Feynman gauge $\xi=1$, and then ${S'}_{\mu\nu}=L_{\mu\nu}$. I'm interested if an analogous result can be obtained in Yang-Mills theories. Specifically, I have two questions

- Is it true that in the axial gauge (in the limit of infinite gauge parameter), with $n=(1,0,0,0)$, then $L_{\mu\nu}=S_{\mu\nu}$ always?
- Is it possible to use $S_{\mu\nu}=-g_{\mu\nu}$ even in Yang-Mills theories with Lorentz gauge fixing term if we are open to the possibility of including external ghosts? Would then one need to include all possible ghost diagrams, including those in which ghosts appear as external states? Is there any literature which goes in this direction?