# Numerator of Massive Vector Propagator and Polarization Sum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, polarization, propagator

I recently showed that for massive spin 1 particles, the polarization sum is given by
$$\sum_{i=1}^2\epsilon^i_\mu\epsilon^i_\nu = -g_{\mu\nu} +\frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{m^2}$$
and that the Feynman propagator of a massive vector field is
$$D_{\mu\nu}(k) =  \frac{-g_{\mu\nu}+k_\mu k_\nu /m^2}{k^2-m^2+i\epsilon}$$
Is there a intuitive reason that we should expect the numerator of the propagator to be equal to the polarization sum?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/548292/

Comment: See Schwartz Section 24.1.3 - it's a consequence of unitarity

Answer (score 1):

The denominator implemented the conservation and on shell condition, where the numerator mostly characterized the amplitude. Since the polarization was like a constrain over the allowed amplitude it made sense that it's on the numerator. (A hand wave argument, the expert should have better answers.)

Answer (score -1):

#### Setup

For a massive spin-1 particle, there are three physical polarization states. The polarization vectors $\epsilon_i^\mu$ describe these states. The sum over polarization vectors essentially sums over the physical degrees of freedom of the particle.

The polarization sum
$$
   \sum_{i=1}^{2} \epsilon_i^\mu \epsilon_i^\nu = -g^{\mu\nu} + \frac{k^\mu k^\nu}{m^2}
   $$
includes a term $-g^{\mu\nu}$ representing the physical polarizations in the Minkowski space and a term $\frac{k^\mu k^\nu}{m^2}$ that accounts for the mass and momentum of the particle.

The Feynman propagator
$$
   D^{\mu\nu}(k) = \frac{-g^{\mu\nu} + \frac{k^\mu k^\nu}{m^2}}{k^2 - m^2 + i\epsilon}
   $$

describes the propagation of a massive spin-1 field. The numerator reflects the degrees of freedom of the field, while the denominator accounts for the dispersion relation (energy-momentum relation) of the particle.

#### Intuitive Connection

The numerator of the propagator essentially captures how the degrees of freedom of the field propagate from one point to another. Since the polarization vectors encapsulate these **degrees of freedom**, it's natural that the numerator mirrors the polarization sum.

The term $\frac{k^\mu k^\nu}{m^2}$ in both expressions arises due to the need to account for the longitudinal mode in massive vector fields, which is a consequence of **gauge fixing** (like in the Proca theory). This term ensures that only physical states contribute to the field's propagation.

In quantum field theory, the propagator is the Green's function of the field equation, akin to how wavefunctions evolve in quantum mechanics. The consistency between the propagator and the polarization sum reflects the underlying quantum mechanical principle that the **sum over all possible states** (polarizations, in this case) yields the complete description of the field's propagation.

Finally, both the polarization sum and the propagator must respect **Lorentz invariance**. The forms they take ensure that all physical degrees of freedom are accounted for while maintaining this symmetry.

#### Conclusion

In essence, the numerator of the propagator being equal to the polarization sum for massive spin-1 particles is not just a mathematical coincidence but a reflection of the deep physical principles of gauge theory, Lorentz invariance, and the quantum mechanical nature of field propagation. This connection is a beautiful example of how various aspects of quantum field theory coalesce to provide a consistent and comprehensive framework for understanding particle physics.